# Visual Basic Keydown computation

Tags: vb.net

I've been doing this a couple of days.
 What I wanted to do is when I hit enter. The number I input in txtbox1 will be multiplied by 12 and then show the output to txtbox2. But no luck. Can some one help me please?
Here's my code:

```
Private Sub txt1_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles txt1.KeyDown
    Dim a, b, c As Integer
    txt1.Text = a
    b=a*12
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
      txt2.text = b
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: This code contains more errors than lines of code. Please get a good introductory book on VB before continuing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be

```
a = txt1.Text
```

instead of

```
txt1.Text = a
```

Otherwise, you just set `txt1.Text` to `0`.

---

Btw, you should propbaly use the [`TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7.aspx) method, to ensure no expection is thrown when the text in the textbox does not contain a valid number.

```
Dim number = 0
If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter AndAlso Int32.TryParse(txt1.Text, number) Then
    txt2.Text = (number * 12).ToString()
End If
```